# HtmlSelect does not trigger event at selection

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I am working on a program for this [website](https://oficinajudicialvirtual.pjud.cl/frameInv.php) using the Java module HtmlUnit. I need to select options from the select fields, but when I do so, it doesn't trigger any events. I have tried a few solutions on forums for this same question (fireEvent method, injecting a JS script to trigger the event), but none have worked so far.

I would really appreciate some help with this one

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get some help you have to provide more details; the version of HtmlUnit you use and your code (as simple as possible). Including a description where your expectation differs from the real results. And of course more details why you think the event is not triggered.

If you think this is a HtmlUnit issue please open a issue in the HtmlUnit issue tracker.

Have written a Wetator (www.wetator.org) test for the web site. Was able to work with all the select boxes and got the appropriate changes on the web site. Based on this i'm really sure this is not a problem with HtmlUnit. Post your code and i will have a look.